# Unable to fetch JSON Data using PHP & Angular JS

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I'm passing ID to fetch JSON encode data using Angular JS.

Here is my controller:

```
    dhmsApp.controller('dhmsDetailsView',function($scope,$http, $routeParams){
     $http.get("include/detailViewBg.php", {params: {id: $routeParams.id}})
        .success(function (response) {$scope.details = response});
});
```

Here is my PHP SELECT Query code (detailViewBg.php) from which JSON is getting Encoded

```
    <?php
include("../include/connection_string.php");

$id = $_GET['id'];

$sql = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM dhms_requirement where id='".$id."'");
if(mysqli_num_rows($sql)){ 
    $data = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
        $data[] = array(
                'id' => $row['id'],
            'rClientName' => $row['rClientName'],
            'rContactNumber' => $row['rContactNumber'],
            'rCompanyName' => $row['rCompanyName'],
            'rEmail' => $row['rEmail'],
            'rRequirement' => $row['rRequirement'],
        );
    }
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($data);
}

$sqlDomain = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM dhms_domain_details where id='".$id."'");
if(mysqli_num_rows($sqlDomain)){
    $dataDomain = array();
    while($rowDomain = mysqli_fetch_array($sqlDomain)){
        $dataDomain[] = array(
                'id' => $rowDomain['id'],
            'dSelectDomain' => $rowDomain['dSelectDomain'],
            'dDomainName' => $rowDomain['dDomainName'],
            'dRegisterDomainFrom' => $rowDomain['dRegisterDomainFrom'],
            'dStartDate' => $rowDomain['dStartDate'],
            'dEndDate' => $rowDomain['dEndDate'],
            'dRegistrationFor' => $rowDomain['dRegistrationFor'],
        );
    }
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($dataDomain);
}



?>
```

Here is my HTML page where I'm fetching my data

```
 <div class="panel-body" ng-repeat="u in details track by $index">
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                        <ul class="list-group">
                            <li class="list-group-item"><strong>Req. NO.</strong> : {{u.id}}</li>
                            <li class="list-group-item"><strong>Contact Number</strong> : {{u.rContactNumber}}</li>
                            <li class="list-group-item"><strong>Email Address</strong> : {{u.rEmail}}</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                        <ul class="list-group">
                            <li class="list-group-item"><strong>Client Name</strong> : {{u.rClientName}}</li>
                            <li class="list-group-item"><strong>Compnay Name</strong> : {{u.rCompanyName}}</li>
                            <li class="list-group-item"><strong>Requirement</strong> : {{u.rRequirement}}</li>

                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
<div class="panel-body" ng-repeat="u in details track by $index">
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <ul class="list-group">
                    <li class="list-group-item"><strong>Req. NO.</strong> : {{u.dSelectDomain}}</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item"><strong>dDomainName</strong> : {{u.dDomainName}}</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item"><strong>dRegisterDomainFrom</strong> : {{u.dRegisterDomainFrom}}</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <ul class="list-group">
                    <li class="list-group-item"><strong>dStartDate</strong> : {{u.dStartDate}}</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item"><strong>dEndDate</strong> : {{u.dEndDate}}</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item"><strong>dRegistrationFor</strong> : {{u.dRegistrationFor}}</li>

                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```

It's showing an error in the console. Please see in the below image
[image: View of Chrome Developer Tools. Javascript error message says "SyntaxError: Unexpected token [ in JSON at position 182]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did echo json data twice, so your response data is invalid json.

```
<?php
include("../include/connection_string.php");

$id = $_GET['id'];

$result = [];

$sql = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM dhms_requirement where id='".$id."'");
if(mysqli_num_rows($sql)){ 
    $data = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
        $data[] = array(
                'id' => $row['id'],
            'rClientName' => $row['rClientName'],
            'rContactNumber' => $row['rContactNumber'],
            'rCompanyName' => $row['rCompanyName'],
            'rEmail' => $row['rEmail'],
            'rRequirement' => $row['rRequirement'],
        );
    }

    //header('Content-type: application/json');
    //echo json_encode($data);

    //Instead of echo data here, just put it into $result array
    $result['requirement_detail'] = $data;
}

$sqlDomain = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM dhms_domain_details where id='".$id."'");
if(mysqli_num_rows($sqlDomain)){
    $dataDomain = array();
    while($rowDomain = mysqli_fetch_array($sqlDomain)){
        $dataDomain[] = array(
                'id' => $rowDomain['id'],
            'dSelectDomain' => $rowDomain['dSelectDomain'],
            'dDomainName' => $rowDomain['dDomainName'],
            'dRegisterDomainFrom' => $rowDomain['dRegisterDomainFrom'],
            'dStartDate' => $rowDomain['dStartDate'],
            'dEndDate' => $rowDomain['dEndDate'],
            'dRegistrationFor' => $rowDomain['dRegistrationFor'],
        );
    }

    //header('Content-type: application/json');
    //echo json_encode($dataDomain);

    //Put this $dataDomain into $result array also.
    $result['domain_data'] = $dataDomain;
}


//Echo json data finally.
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($result);

?>
```

And update your html part

```
<!--<div class="panel-body" ng-repeat="u in details track by $index">-->
<!-- Careful the details.requirement_detail -->
<div class="panel-body" ng-repeat="u in details.requirement_detail track by $index">
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                        <ul class="list-group">
                            <li class="list-group-item"><strong>Req. NO.</strong> : {{u.id}}</li>
                            <li class="list-group-item"><strong>Contact Number</strong> : {{u.rContactNumber}}</li>
                            <li class="list-group-item"><strong>Email Address</strong> : {{u.rEmail}}</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                        <ul class="list-group">
                            <li class="list-group-item"><strong>Client Name</strong> : {{u.rClientName}}</li>
                            <li class="list-group-item"><strong>Compnay Name</strong> : {{u.rCompanyName}}</li>
                            <li class="list-group-item"><strong>Requirement</strong> : {{u.rRequirement}}</li>

                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
<!--<div class="panel-body" ng-repeat="u in details track by $index">-->
<!-- Careful the details.domain_data-->
<div class="panel-body" ng-repeat="u in details.domain_data track by $index">
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <ul class="list-group">
                    <li class="list-group-item"><strong>Req. NO.</strong> : {{u.dSelectDomain}}</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item"><strong>dDomainName</strong> : {{u.dDomainName}}</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item"><strong>dRegisterDomainFrom</strong> : {{u.dRegisterDomainFrom}}</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <ul class="list-group">
                    <li class="list-group-item"><strong>dStartDate</strong> : {{u.dStartDate}}</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item"><strong>dEndDate</strong> : {{u.dEndDate}}</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item"><strong>dRegistrationFor</strong> : {{u.dRegistrationFor}}</li>

                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**Why should do like this?**

1. When you post your question:

   `echo json_encode($data);` after `SELECT * FROM dhms_requirement`,

   and then, again,

   `echo json_encode($dataDomain);` after `SELECT * FROM dhms_domain_details`,

   so your response data should like this:

   `[...][...]`

   It's invalid json data, as you saw the error in the console.
2. After updating php, I wrapped two select result into `$result` array, so your response data like this:

   `{"requirement_detail":[...],"domain_data":[...]}`
3. When loop in html template, your reference to detail, which is responsive data, divided into 2 parts, use `detail.requirement_detail` as first part, and `domain_data` as second part.

**Should works.**

Comment: can you please check my html part where i'm fetching data.. actually when i'm added your solution, error from the console vanish, but data is not getting print on html portion.

can you please check where my code is lacking

Comment: In my Question i have added HTML please check with in Question

Comment: Thank you so much buddy for great support.. it work forme ... and i can see data into my html files...